# pymysql returns error if long query is used

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

With the following code if I use a long query then I get an error. Is there a limit on the query size that I give?

Sorry, but I can't share the exact query that I'm passing. If the same query is given in MySQL workbench then the data is returned correctly. Any advice would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql
import pandas as pd


connection = pymysql.connect(host = host,
                       user = user,
                       db = db,
                       password = password,
                        port = port)

def sql_to_df(sql_query):
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection)
    connection.close()
    return df

query = '''long query'''

#use pandas to pass SQL query
df = sql_to_df(query)    
df.head()
```

This error is returned:

```
    497             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
    498             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 499             chunksize=chunksize)
    500 
    501     try:

   1602         if chunksize is not None:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: does the sql run in mysql  command line interface?

Comment: I ran it in MySQL workbench. I'm not familiar with running SQL queries from the command line.

Comment: How long does SQL take to run on workbench. and you should include the sql in case there is something wrong with it.

Comment: It takes a few seconds to return on SQL workbench. Unfortunately, I can't share the SQL query because it contains proprietary info. I know that there is nothing wrong with it because it runs correctly in MySQL workbench.

Comment: Well then switch drivers -- pip install MySQL-python   ..  http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: In  few second -- how many rows are return and columns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different tool to query the database (mysql.connector). I was able to find additional insight into the error.

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

After removing that from my query it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sql_to_df(sql_query):
     df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection)
     connection.close()
     return df

query = '''long query'''

#use pandas to pass SQL query
df = sql_to_df(query)    
df.head()
```

You just need below..

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection) 
connection.close()
df.head()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Merlin, but that doesn't help. I'm already closing the connection in the function. I can't close it twice.

Comment: Do not use the function it is not needed.

Comment: also add "limit" to query to see if smaller query works

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion re. the shorter code. The code works with shorter queries, my question is regarding this large one.